# Size Annotation in Spring Boot is returning 400 Bad Request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-validator

**I am not getting message error while executing `@Size` annotation in spring boot bean class**

below are my files
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.val</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring-boot-validation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring-boot-validation</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

UserInput.java

```
package com.val.Springbootvalidation;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserInput {
    @NotNull(message = "lastname can not be null")
    @Size(min=3, max= 20, message = "Lastname should be between 3 and 20")
    private String lastName;
    private String middleName;
    private String firstName;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private Integer siblings;
}
```

User.java

```
package com.val.Springbootvalidation;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String lastName;
    private String middleName;
    private String firstName;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private Integer siblings;
}
```

SpringBootValidationApplication.java (Main loader)

```
package com.val.Springbootvalidation;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootValidationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootValidationApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Input I am passing is

```
{
    "firstName":"s"
}
```

Response I am getting is

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-07-27T07:20:04.655+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api/user/save"
}
```

In the console log it is showing

```
[org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public com.val.Springbootvalidation.User com.val.Springbootvalidation.UserController.save(com.val.Springbootvalidation.UserInput): [Field error in object 'userInput' on field 'lastName': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.userInput.lastName,NotNull.lastName,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [userInput.lastName,lastName]; arguments []; default message [lastName]]; default message [lastname can not be null]] ]
```

Comment: Could you clarify if the problems is that you're getting a 400 Bad Request (as the title suggests) or that you're not getting the error message in the response (as it's stated in the problem's description)? Also, I reckon we're missing a class with the REST API definition, aren't we?

Comment: Which is how it should work. The request is invalid (validation fails) thus a 400.

Comment: yes, but we configured the message on failure in UserInput bean. that is not being displayed on failure. I want that to be displayed.

Comment: I have same issue after upgrading spring boot to 2.3. Try it with 2.2.9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring not returning default validation error responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188531/spring-not-returning-default-validation-error-responses)

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot 2.3.2 has issues with validation messages, or behaviour changed.
Try to downgrade to Spring Boot 2.2.9

Comment: This change in behavior between Boot 2.2 and 2.3 is documented in the project release notes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content

Comment: The comment  from @ScottFrederick should be marked as the correct answer. Thank you Scott.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, There is issue with Spring 2.3.2 version that Size annotation will not provide proper restful response. After downgrading it to version 2.2.9 it worked as expected. It is returning proper Json with custom error message.

Comment: This change in behavior between Boot 2.2 and 2.3 is documented in the project release notes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content