# Spring not returning default validation error responses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I'm trying to get the default Spring 400 constrain violation errors working.
I'm expecting this:

```
{
    ....
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
        {
            ....
            "defaultMessage": "must not be null",
            ....
        }
    ],
    "message": "Validation failed for object='notNullRequest'. Error count: 1",
    ....
}
```

But I get:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-07-31T08:30:06.992+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/v0.1/checkouts/1"
}
```

My POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>hidden</groupId>
    <artifactId>hidden</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hidden</name>
    <description>hidden</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.12</org.projectlombok.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>hidden</id>
            <name>hidden</name>
            <url>hidden</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

REST Resource I'm trying to validate:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<CheckoutDto> createCheckout(@PathVariable Long id,
                                                  @Valid @RequestBody CheckoutProcessRequest request) {
```

The DTO has validations like:

```
@NotNull
@JsonProperty("payment_type")
private PaymentType paymentType;
```

And I get a proper message in the log:

```
2020-07-31 11:30:06.983  WARN 93126 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [1] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.hidden.payments.rest.model.CheckoutDto> com.hidden.payments.rest.CheckoutsResource.createCheckout(java.lang.Long,com.hidden.payments.rest.model.CheckoutProcessRequest): [Field error in object 'checkoutProcessRequest' on field 'paymentType': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.checkoutProcessRequest.paymentType,NotNull.paymentType,NotNull.com.hidden.payments.rest.model.PaymentType,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [checkoutProcessRequest.paymentType,paymentType]; arguments []; default message [paymentType]]; default message [must not be null]] ]
```

So any ideas what could interfering with the response?
I have no recollection of ever having to do anything specific to get the proper constraint violation responses in latest Spring versions.

Thanks!

Comment: According to your expectation described above, I think you need a custom error object instead of the default one spring boot creates. correct? how to did you handled the required steps for `custom error handling`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.3 omits the `errors` and `message` fields in error responses by default to reduce the chance that sensitive information is included in a response. You can restore the previous behavior by setting the following properties:

```
server.error.include-message=always
server.error.include-binding-errors=always
```

See the 2.3 [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content) and [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#server-properties) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Sprint Boot 2.3 has issues with validation messages, or behaviour changed.
Duplicated question under
[Size Annotation in Spring Boot is returning 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110587/size-annotation-in-spring-boot-is-returning-400-bad-request/63187267#63187267)