# javax.validation.ValidationException is not working in Spring boot 2.7.5 higher versions

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

javax.validation.ValidationException is not working after upgrading the Spring boot to 2.7.5 version .I am able to see the proper description in debug mode but it throwing the exception properly .The error has to thrown as "User not Found in the System" but it is throwing Unauthorized Error .But it was working properly before upgrade of Spring boot to higher version . In higher versions javax.validation.ValidationException is not existing in that how the error has to thrown in proper way .Please find the code syntax and pom.xml . Appreciate any help

Error Message :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-04-06T17:03:04.171+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/type/get"
}

     @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public Object getSerachData(@RequestParam(value = "user") String user,
                                                @RequestParam(value = "customerId", required = false) String customerId,
                                                @RequestParam(value = "system", required = false) String system,
                                                 throws ParseException, JsonProcessingException, javax.xml.bind.ValidationException {       
            if (user != null && !user.isEmpty())
                documentMap.put("Type.user", user);
            if (customerId != null && !customerId.isEmpty())
                documentMap.put("Type.customerId", customerId);
            if (system != null && !system.isEmpty())
                documentMap.put("Type.system", system);     
            if (database.isEmpty())
                throw new ValidationException(RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND);
            return getPrettyDocument(database);
        }
    
    
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class ValidationExceptionHandler {
    
        @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
        public void constraintViolationException(HttpServletResponse response,ConstraintViolationException e) throws IOException {
            Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations ) {
                strBuilder.append(violation.getMessage() + '\n');
            }
            ResponseEntity.status(BAD_REQUEST);
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        }
        @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
        public void dateViolationException(HttpServletResponse response, ValidationException e) throws IOException {
           if(e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("Resource Not Found")){
               ResponseEntity.status(NOT_FOUND);
               response.sendError(NOT_FOUND.value(), e.getMessage());
            }else{
               if(e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("User Not Found in the system")){
                   ResponseEntity.status(UNAUTHORIZED);
                   response.sendError(UNAUTHORIZED.value(), e.getMessage());
           }
            else{
                ResponseEntity.status(BAD_REQUEST);
                response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }}

Maven.pm.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>SampleService</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        
            <name>SampleService</name>
            <description>Project for SampleService </description>
        
            <properties>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                <springboot.version>2.7.5</springboot.version>
                <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
                <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</surefire-plugin.version>
                <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
            </properties>
        
            <dependencyManagement>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                        <scope>import</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </dependencyManagement>
        
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
                </dependency>
        
            </dependencies>
        
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>spring-milestone</id>
                    <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
                    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                            </systemProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>
                                <source>1.8</source>
                                <target>1.8</target>
                                <uberJar>true</uberJar>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </project>
```

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you upgrading from? If it was prior to Spring Boot 2.3 then this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63194596/1299533.

Comment: @ScottFrederick I am using Spring boot 2.7.5 and tried your suggestion and kept the mentioned properties in application.properties but still the issue is not resolved .Do we need use custom handling